# Invalid argument. Culture is not supported.

Tags: c#

Проект работал нормально, запушил его на Гит, пересобрал все refferences, перебилдил. И вот такая ошибка вылезла:

> Parameter name: name is an invalid culture identifier.

Ниже привожу output:

> 1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: VideoPlayerConverter, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1820,5): error MSB3095: Invalid argument. Culture is not supported.
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1820,5): error MSB3095: Parameter name: name
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1820,5): error MSB3095: # is an invalid culture identifier.
>   ========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

Заранее всем спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Это все случилось с проектом скачанным с ГИТ, в ГИТ добавлял все что нужно.

Comment: мб попробовать Update-Package -reinstall

Comment: Нугеты переинсталлил, не помогло

Comment: "Parameter name: name %тут должна быть локаль, но ее ней% is an invalid culture identifier.". Надо выяснить почему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема заключалась в проверке всех refferences, не все подключаемые dll корректно отрабатывают при ссылке на них, хотя при добавлении их может не возникать ошибок. Таким образом, при возникновении такого рода ошибки проверяйте все refferences